# Can you create Winforms in SharePoint 2010 with MS Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a Form interface on SharePoint 2010 that has a Access database engine. I know I've seen MS Access 2013 does this well, and I believe I read that MS Access 2010 can also do this. Is it possible to have this feature work with MS Access 2007? I do not just want to upload my access workbook, or work off lists in SharePoint. I want users to actually have a Form on SharePoint 2010 and enter data through that form.

Thanks in advance,

Sarah G.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need at least MS Access 2010 to create a "Web Database". 2007 does not have this. 2013 introduced the "Access Web App" which is not compatible with Web Databases and can only work in SharePoint 2013.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Build-an-Access-database-to-share-on-the-Web-cca08e35-8e51-45ce-9269-8942b0deab26